# Slow down an jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I have an animation that i have been trying to slow down but so far i have been unsucsessful i have tried duration and adding the time at the end however the animation seems to run at the same speed.

any help would be great.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    // Change the width of the div
    var i = 0;
    $(".progress-bar span").animate({
        width: "100%"
        },
        {step: function(){
        //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
        console.log($(this).width());
        },
         complete : function(){
             console.log("finished");
         }
        },2000);
});
```

see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Jrand/8jXDK/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the duration argument for the animation as part of the second argument which is the options object.  jQuery's `.animate()` takes several forms.  The form you are using takes two objects and the second object can include the `duration` as a property of that second argument like I show here:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    // Change the width of the div
    var i = 0;
    $(".progress-bar span").animate({
        width: "100%"
        },
        {
            duration: 5000,
            step: function() {
                //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
                console.log($(this).width());
            },
            complete: function() {
                 console.log("finished");
            }
     });
});
```

Comment: Isn't this really a comment?

Comment: ah,there you go.Sorry,I posted the comment before you updated the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$("document").ready(function(){
// Change the width of the div
var i = 0;
$(".progress-bar span").animate({
    width: "100%"

    },
    {
        duration: 5000,
        step: function(){
                //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
                console.log($(this).width());
            },
         complete : function(){
             console.log("finished");
         }
    });
 });
```

Your updated jsfiddle code >> http://jsfiddle.net/8jXDK/4/

Answer (score 1):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8jXDK/3/

simply moving the duration to the proper location solves this issue.

JS:

```
// Change the width of the div
var i = 0;
$(".progress-bar span").animate(
    {
        width: "100%"
    },             
    {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function(){
            //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
            console.log($(this).width());
        },
        complete : function(){
            console.log("finished");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the animate function has a preset duration of fast/slow both are 200ms and 400ms respectively. I did hacked a work around as follows...

```
var progress = 100; //or the maximum range where your progress bar stops...
var progress_speed = 1000; //varying this number will determine how fast or how slow progress bar goes...
var counter = 0;            
var width_animate_b = setInterval(function() {              
    if(counter < progress) {                    
         counter++;
         $(".progress-bar").attr('aria-valuenow', counter);
         $(".progress-bar").css('width', counter + "%");
         $(".progress-bar").prop('Counter', counter);
         $(".progress-bar").text(counter + '%');
    } else {                        
         clearInterval(width_animate_b)
    }
}, progress_speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a duration attribute to the second object parameter.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    // Change the width of the div
    var i = 0;
    $(".progress-bar span").animate({
        width: "100%"
        },
        {step: function(){
        //console.log( "width: ", i++ );
        console.log($(this).width());
        },
         complete : function(){
             console.log("finished");
         },
         duration: 10000
        });
});
```